# Slack app that opens a user interactive GUI

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

My office is teleworking right now we have a morning check in at 6:30 am. I volunteered to create a python GUI that users can click on a button and check in, rather than our phones blowing up with "Check in" messages every morning.

The GUI is finished but now I'm stuck at trying to figure out how to implement it in Slack. This is the GUI I created:

```
import datetime
import tkinter

test_user = "Test"

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Morning Check In")
root.resizable(width = "false", height = "false")
root.minsize(width = 500, height = 500)
root.maxsize(width = 500, height = 500)

def clock():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    return current_time

def color_label(any_label, user, time):
    any_label.configure(text = " " + user + " : Checked In at " + time, bg = "green", fg = "white")

frame1 = tkinter.Frame(root, borderwidth = 0, relief = 'ridge')
frame2 = tkinter.Frame(root, borderwidth = 0, relief = 'ridge')

frame1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = "nsew")
frame2.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = "nsew")

label1 = tkinter.Label(frame1, text = test_user)
button1 = tkinter.Button(frame2, text = "Check In", command = lambda: color_label(label1, test_user, clock()))

label1.pack(fill = 'x')
button1.pack(fill = 'x')

root.mainloop()
```

Now, I've gone through dozens of articles on how to create bots and stuff about Webhooks and things that I don't understand.

Basically, I envisioned creating a bot with a slash command that opens the GUI and setting a timer that runs the slash command at 6:30 am Monday to Friday.

First of all, is this realistic? Possible? Second, how in the world would I implement this? I'm stuck! Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not possible. You can use a chat-based interface and you can add actions buttons to your responses, but you cannot pop up custom UI. The closest thing to that would be posting a link that people would click to open your website in their browser and use your application there.

Comment: Hm. I thought this would be simple. Just create a simple check in app but I keep running into issues. I'll keep looking for a way to do it. Thank you!